# How to bind a stacklayout in a viewcell in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I like the idea of having a ListView and just bind data and specify a DataTemplate for list item layout. But here is where I dont get it. Say I have:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems  { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to populate a list in ListView which looks as follows:

> (Orderid)
>
> > ItemName, ItemName
>
> (Orderid)
>
> > ItemName, ItemName, ItemName

and so on.

Edit: I dont want to list the Order Id but I want to be able to fetch it on a click event in the list.

I cant find anywhere If I can bind a collection in a ViewCell. How should I go about this? Is there a way to have nested ViewCells in this matter?

/Mike

Answer (score 0):

I presume from your post that you are wanting the CustomerName to almost act as a section header.

You should look at the example here for creating grouped list views in Xamarin.Forms and you will be able to recreate the desired visual:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/LabelledSectionsList

Good luck

Comment: Thanx for you answer. I have edited the question a bit. I dont want to display the ordername as a header, I just need to fetch the OrderId from a Click event in the list.

Comment: You will essentially have an observable collection of Order objects where you only want to display the OrderItem.ItemName property? You can either use the bindable SelectedItem property of the ListView to determine the selected object or use CommandParameters. I am of course presuming you are utilising an MVVM type approach

Comment: Yes, thats correct. The problem isnt how Im supposed to catch the SelectedItem event, im doing that already, the issue here is how do I display the items in the OrderItem collection. What I believe I cant just send it to the VewCell ( for the Order)  to populate the order items? Or can I? Anyhow I havent found any way to this.